# Remove submap of TreeMap in logarithmic time

Tags: java, data-structures

I am using a `TreeMap<Integer, Integer>` to represent a sorted list which can have duplicate elements. The key corresponds to an arbitrary value in the list and the mapped value corresponds to the number of occurrences. I am using a sorted list concept because I need to efficiently operate over sublists (log *n* time) and I am using a `TreeMap` because Java doesn't have any default sorted list implementation.

However, I noticed that the performance of my algorithm was slower than expected, so after doing some research, it appears that the `subMap` method takes *O*(log *n* + *k*) time, where *n* is the size of the map and *k* is the number of elements within the sub map. For large values of *k* relative to *n*, this approaches linear time.

How can I operate over submaps (sublists) in sublinear time; or alternatively, is there a better way I can represent a sorted list in Java?

The motivation behind this question: imagining the tree map as a binary search tree, I'd like to find the first node of some subtree, then use that as the entire tree itself, effectively removing the rest of the tree. Ideally this would only take *O(log n)* time.

Comment: I've edited the question for more clarity: I want to remove an entire portion of the tree, so in other words, remove all *but* k elements. Also, I meant *log n + k*, not multiplied, that was a typo.

Comment: Okay, so the submaps are always rooted at a single element; they won't span multiple roots? Meaning you can't remove arbitrary spans of consecutive elements, correct?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then the answer is yes. This would correspond I believe to tail map in that case actually, but I believe the complexity is still the same. I'll try it out in my code though.

Comment: Let's say you were storing the numbers 1 through 7 in a balanced binary tree with 4 at the top, 2 and 6 at the next level, and 1/3/5/7 at the last level. Removing 1-3 would mean removing the 2 node. Removing 5-7 would mean removing 6. But you wouldn't attempt to remove, say, 2-4 or 3-6, since those number ranges span multiple subtrees. Is this correct?...

Comment: ...If so, it sounds like you're leaning heavily on the "list" having a tree representation, and aren't looking for an array-based data structure. Is that also correct?

Comment: I see your point now, in that case, they indeed could span multiple elements, which means I'm probably not using the best data structure for what I'm looking for. I'm not leaning particularly on using a tree implementation, it's just that Java doesn't seem to have a default sorted list implementation other than sets (though Java's not my main language, so I may be mistaken).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google's [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) library has an [extensive suite of collection classes](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/package-summary.html) that complement the ones in the standard library nicely.

> Guava is a set of core Java libraries from Google that includes new collection types (such as multimap and multiset), immutable collections, a graph library, and utilities for concurrency, I/O, hashing, caching, primitives, strings, and more! It is widely used on most Java projects within Google, and widely used by many other companies as well.

You might like their [`SortedMultiset`](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/SortedMultiset.html) interface for collections that maintain elements in a sorted order and allow for duplicates. Implementations include:

- [`ImmutableSortedMultiset`](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableSortedMultiset.html)
- [`TreeMultiset`](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/TreeMultiset.html)

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question - in particular "effectively removing the rest of the tree. Ideally this would only take O(log n) time."

Comment: @MotiNK It answers "...or alternatively, is there a better way I can represent a sorted list in Java?"